# Seeing a pre-logon app's GUI after logon (or ever)

Tags: windows, boot, login, gui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to select the account on the login screen of Windows7 by start typing the name?](https://superuser.com/questions/236690/how-to-select-the-account-on-the-login-screen-of-windows7-by-start-typing-the-nam)

I'm looking for either a method to achieve this, or a clear reason why it's not possible.

I use *Scheduled Tasks* to start an app with a GUI at system startup. I want to see that GUI's screen after logon without restarting it. I'm willing to type a password and/or re-logon and/or or use whatever app or tool to help, including changing the way I run the GUI app. It just can't wait for a user logon to start.

How do I do it? Or if it's absolutely impossible, why? I've read about "Shatter attacks" but that doesn't seem to cover this.

I'm most interested in XP and Windows7.

If multiple solutions exist, of course I'd prefer the most convenient, flexible and/or open source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [Session 0 Isolation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/hardware/gg463353.aspx) and the [ACLs on the login desktop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms682573(VS.85).aspx), Windows NT 6 is *intentionally* designed to make this almost impossible to achieve.  [The winlogon desktop is intentionally protected](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc780332(WS.10).aspx#sectionSection1) from processes that would otherwise be capable of injecting password-stealing code; and programs running in session 0 (which [includes tasks run from the Scheduled Tasks service](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/255544)) are intentionally protected from interaction with programs running on interactive window stations in other sessions.  The design intention is that it is very hard to fake the login prompt, very hard to grab passwords, and very hard to make use of the insecure message-passing shared-resource nature of the Windows GUI to perform privilege escalation.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful response & links. From the diagrams in [Session 0 Isolation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/hardware/gg463353.aspx), it seems one could create a _Session 2_ then run applications under it, all from _Session 0_. No?

Comment: Not believing this at first, I pursued numerous leads, and they were all dead ends. Only the existence of some undocumented feature would do it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible.  In order to display a GUI there needs to be an interactive session which is only attainable when a user logs on.

Comment: I wouldn't say that, the login screen is interactive and I have seen applications run on it. :-)